# jsTree Remember last expanded/collapsed on refresh

Tags: jstree

Using jstree on refreh keeps unselected nodes if expanded or collapsed.

But, If I collapse selected checkbox on refresh it will expand. How to keep if I collapse/expand on refresh?

I use "state" plugin.

In other way it expands if I refresh. I want to keep if I some selected node collapsed to be collapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are bug in old version.

Works on version jsTree - v3.3.1 - 2016-05-05 https://github.com/vakata/jstree/releases/tag/3.3.1